# How to change fillable variable instance programmatically in Eloquent Model?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, model

What I want to do is programmatically change the value of **$fillable** variable. I am using **fillable** method of **GuardsAttributes** trait to set new fillable variables. However, When the user call Model::create facade from the controller, the fillable attribute was not updated.

```
    $model = new Modal();
    $model->fillable(array_merge($model->getFillable(),["new_field"]));
```

What I want to do is, updating Post::create instance with new fillable attribute. I checked the service container but there is nothing similar with Model triggered on there. So, How can I update the current Model instance?

Answer (score 0):

That because `$model->fillable()` is an instance function: defined on an instance of Model; so when you change the $fillable variable you are changing it only on that particular Model instance. The `Model::create()` function instead is a static function and dinamically defined only on the Model class.

Try this in sequence:

```
$model = new Model();
$model->fillable(array_merge($model->getFillable(),["new_field"]));
$model->fill($your_data)->save();
```

Alternatively instead of set fillable() on every model you could try to set unguarded=true for the Class when the app start:

```
Model::unguard(true)
```

Comment: But this is hard to implement. Because, I am getting new fields from the service providers so I need to inject them out of the box.

Comment: I update the answer, should works with the last line.

Comment: And this time, setting unguard is a little unsecure right? Do you think, No difference between setting unguard or appending fillable?

Comment: Yes it's unsecure. I will go with the fillable() function, but unguard() is a good choice if you have strict control on your input data.